# Red-blue-blinking LED = standardized for Bluetooth pairing mode?

Tags: led, pairing

As I observed all target hardware Bluetooth devices (adapter, headsets) show a red+blue blinking LED when toggled to pairing mode.

Is this standardized?

Peter